# Overlapping UIView - How to receive touches?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, touches

I'm building an iOS app with an Instagram style center tab (the ones that are raised from the tab bar).

I have my custom view added as a subview to the tabBar, with it's Y value set to -27.0.

The problem I'm having is that only the bottom half of my view receives touches. I've read this question:

[UIView. Why Does A Subviews Outside its Parent's Extent Not Receive Touches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844356/uiview-why-does-a-subviews-outside-its-parents-extent-not-receive-touches)

I think this will solve my problem, but I'm a little confused as to where each method goes. Will I need to subclass UITabBarController?

Comment: Please don't vote down the question without leaving a comment so I can improve it; that's not helpful at all.

Comment: I think it is possible you were downvoted because this *appears* to be less of a real question and more of a duplicate.  Also, it doesn't show work on your part, and is a little hard to answer without investigating the other question, and then trying to guess at which methods you are talking about.  What I would suggest is that you create a ["Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example"](http://sscce.org/) that repros your exact problem, including your best guess at a solution.  You can then use that to [edit] your question and provide more details about it.

Comment: You should make your question a little shorter and then add it as a comment to the already mentioned other question, since this is not a real question on its own.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I'll update & modify my question - as well as showing why this is a fairly different situation; I'd have probably been better not saying I'd read the other question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, yes I believe you'll need to create a custom subclass of UITabBar and implement the hitTest and pointInside methods as advised in the answer you linked to.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the best way to do it. Thanks for taking the time to answer.