# Nested UIScrollView with pagingEnabled on the encompassing one doesn't receive the first bottom swipe after page change

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I'am facing a little problem with my App that has a bit complicated structure :

So first things first the views hirearchy :

```
|- UICollectionView (horizontal scrolling)
 -> UICollectionViewCell
  |-> UIScrollView A (PagingEnabled = YES, vertical scrolling only)
    |-> UIImageView = page 1
    |-> UIScrollView B (PagingEnabled = NO, vertical scrolling only) = page 2
      |-> UIView (content...)
```

The problem is that when I scroll on UIScrollView A to make page 2 appear, the first scroll to the see the bottom on UIScrollView B is ignored, no scroll at all, but the second one has the right behaviour.

I think that it's a kind of "focusing" problem, but I can't figure out how to make this work properly.

Any clue on how to give this first touch on page 2 to the right UIScrollView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `hitTest:withEvent:` method? This method helps you choose which view should receive the touch.

For example, you could subclass `UIScrollView` and set your **UIScrollView A**'s class the new class you just created. Adding the code below to this custom `UIScrollView` class will let you deliver the touch to it's **child view**'s first

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UIView *subView in self.subviews) {
        // Convert the point to the subView's coordinate system.
        CGPoint pointForTargetView = [subView convertPoint:point fromView:self];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(subView.bounds, pointForTargetView)) {
            // Calling subView's hitTest:withEvent get the right view
            return [subView hitTest:pointForTargetView withEvent:event];
        }
    }

    UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

//  // Uncomment if you want to make the view 'transparent' to touches:
//  // meaning the parts of the view without any subview will deliver the touch
//  // to the views 'behind' it
//  if (hitView == self) {
//      return nil;
//  }

    return hitView;
}
```

For more detailed info please check [WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) - **Advanced Scrollviews and Touch Handling Techniques** (around 15:00 is where this subject starts).

Also, thanks to [Tim Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25585617/2177402) for the clue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and links, I made it using another gesture recognizer, recognizing the first gesture only and scrolling programmatically by setting the content offset.
You code is definitely a better way to perform this.

Comment: No problem, I hope it's going to help others in the future. Cheers